# cannot move to a subdirectory of itself

Tags: centos, bash, mv

I have 2 folders:

```
/home/sphinx/articlesdb/
```

and:

```
/home/sphinx/tmp/articlesdb/
```

I want to move and overwrite all of the files from `tmp` into the main folder.

I am currently using:

```
mv -f /home/sphinx/tmp/articlesdb/ /home/sphinx/
```

But I get this error:

```
mv: cannot move `/home/sphinx/tmp/articlesdb/' to a subdirectory of itself, `/home/sphinx/articlesdb'
```

It needs to do this as fast as possible so I don't want to copy.

Should I remove `/home/sphinx/articlesdb/` completely and then run the `mv` command or do I just need to tweak the command slightly?

Comment: Are there any linked folders involved here?

Comment: no i dont think so

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you ensure that `/home/sphinx/articlesdb` is empty, then do

```
cd /home/sphinx/tmp/articlesdb
mv * /home/sphinx/articlesdb/
```

Comment: Or if you go to `/home/sphinx/tmp` and do `mv articlesdb /home/sphinx/`.

Answer (score 0):

Decided to delete the original folder and then move it from `tmp`.

Comment: Glad you resolved [or created a work around for] this issue. Please be sure to mark your answer as "accepted" when you are able.